# Jquery post single variable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have "create user" form which has to check if the username already exists. For that, I made an onclick function on a button starting this script:

```
$.ajax({
type: \"POST\",
dataType: \"json\",
url: \"test.php\",
data: $('input[name=Username]').val(),
contentType: \"application/json; charset=utf-8\",
success: function(data){
alert('Items added');
},
error: function(e){
console.log(e.message);
}
});
```

However, nothing happens, even not the alert stating succes!
Please help me out how to post that single variable and how to get the result from the PHP page checking the existance of the username.

Comment: Where do those `\"` come from?

Comment: Remove code from onclick event, create a function and remove escapes from ".

Comment: Is there error message being logged to the console?

Comment: `contentType` is the `Content-Type` being ***sent to*** the server in the ***request***.  Remove that, you are ***not sending*** JSON.

Comment: I am sorry, the \" comes from the PHP echo("the script") command. They are escapes from the PHP echo functions, should not be the problem.

Beside that, I guess I want to use JSON because the script should make a text field red if the username exists or continue is the username is available. So you the output of the JSON response to check whether the username is free.

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` key needs a `value` which is an object, like so:

```
data: {username: $('input[name=Username]').val())},
```

This way, the POST value `username` will be created.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't escape random bits of JS. Get rid of the `\`s
2. It is much easier to deal with submitted data if you format using a standard form mime type rather then just sending a single raw string. `data: { keyName: $('input[name=Username]').val() }`
3. You aren't sending a JSON text. Get rid of `contentType: etc etc`. (Leaving it in may cause PHP to go "This isn't form data, I can't populate `$_POST` with it"). Let jQuery determine the content-type it sends.

Then you can access `$_POST['keyName']` in your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign the variable to an item that can be referenced in the `$_POST` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {user:$('input[name=Username]').val()},
    success: function(data){
        alert('Items added');
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Then in `test.php`, just retrieve `$_POST['user']`.

Edit - I removed contentType (thanks Rocket). I also removed the dataType, because you don't need to do that if you properly set the header on `test.php`:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: removed `contentType`, it was just there from the copy/paste. Also removed `dataType:json`, and informed how to properly set the header of test.php.

Comment: Keeping `dataType: 'json'` is fine, just in case.

Comment: yes, but its completely unnecessary and redundant when setting the header of the file correctly. just in case of what, the apache server stops recognizing header declarations?